# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'hotelier/auth'

Tags: angular, routes

I've a problem with angular route. When I first time run the project in new tab, browser returns me the error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'hotelier/auth'

But if I refresh the tab, it works fine and The most interesting thing that I have in the project is nowhere in this sigment **'hotelier/auth'** I've only **'admin/auth**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'admin', component: AppComponent, children: [
    { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
    { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'countries', component: CountriesComponent },
      { path: 'cities', component: CitiesComponent },
      { path: 'applications', component: ApplicationsComponent },
      { path: 'services-groups', component: ServicesGroupsComponent },
      { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent },
      { path: 'facilities', component: FacilitiesComponent },
      { path: 'beds', component: BedsComponent },
      { path: 'property-types', component: PropertyTypesComponent },
      { path: 'personal-languages', component: PersonalLanguagesComponent },
      { path: 'properties', component: PropertiesComponent },
      { path: 'properties/add', component: AddPropertyComponent },
      { path: 'properties/:id/edit', component: EditPropertyComponent },
      { path: 'properties/:id/add-room-type', component: 
         AddNewRoomTypeComponent },
      { path: 'properties/:id/edit-room-type/:id', component: 
         EditRoomTypeComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/admin/home' }
    ] }
  ] }
];
```

Comment: Look where to try to navigate to `auth` in your code. The error may be there.